# Type annotation for function returning a lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, annotations, python-3.6

I’m very fond of the idea of using type annotations in Python. I know how to do such like in this simple example:

```
def foo(bar : int, lol : int) -> int:
     return bar*lol
```

But I have no clue of how to do so when my function is going to return a lambda:

```
def line(slope : float, b : float) -> lambda:
     return lambda x: slope*x + b
```

This example generates an error, and I wonder what’s the keyword I’m supposed to use for this return type.

Perhaps this doesn’t seem so useful but I want to keep my code consistently annotated and being unable to do so with these type of functions is really bothering me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the interpreter is never really checking these but my attempt was invalid syntax. What you have proposed works just fine and makes sense for me. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [Callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) to type hint the return:

```
from typing import Callable

def line(slope: float, b : float) -> Callable[[float], float]:
     return lambda x: slope*x + b
```

Comment: What if I want to distinguish between lambda/regular function and class with `__call__` method (which is also callable)? e.g. `inspect.isfunction`/`inspect.isclass` return values?

Comment: @MishaBrt That would depend on what specifically you're looking for. "Regular functions" do have a `__call__` method on them, so that can't be relied on. Why do you care what type of function it is?

Comment: In the second case I might be able to create different instances of a class and correspondingly would have different bound methods for my "callable". Therefore I need separation for two different entities produced